# Using Type::Tiny, is there a way to stringify, deflate or uncoerce a date type?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I've built a module that uses [Type::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/release/Type-Tiny) and it's working fine.

Now I have to write a TO_JSON subroutine and I'm hoping I don't have to write a deflate method for each piece of data. Is there a way to define a deflation method in the type definition with Type::Tiny?  An 'uncoerce' so to speak. I haven't found anything in the docs but I may just not be looking for the right keyword.

I am not using an object frame like Moo or Moose, but I am using an object for the data.

A simplified example looks like

```
package My::Object::Types;
# the usual stuff, strict, etc.
my $meta = __PACKAGE__->meta;
my $_Date = Type::Tiny::Class->new( class => 'Time::Piece' );
my $_Due = $meta->add_type(
  name => 'Due',
  parent => $_Date,
);

package My::Object;
# again, the usual strict, warnings, etc.
sub new {
  my ( $class, $args ) = @_;
  my $self = bless {}, $class;

  for my $attr ( keys %$args ) {
    my $type = ucfirst $attr;
    my $set_attribute = "set_$attr";

    *$set_attribute = sub {
      my ( $self, $value ) = @_;
      $value = $self->$type->assert_coerce( $value ) if $self->$type->has_coercion;
      my $invalid = $self->$type->validate( $value );
      carp $invalid && return if $invalid;
      $self->{data}{$attr} = $value;
    };

    $attr = sub { return $_[0]->{data}{$attr} };
  }

  return $self;
}
```

Comment: Are you using that with an object framework like Moo or on its own? Please show an example of how you use it. In general, Type::Tiny only _validates_ data against a set of rules. It **does not** represent internal data. Your data is still your data, and once it's done validating it's stored as the same data. If you need to serialize that data according to your business rules, you should be using objects instead.

Comment: So, I would need to add a _deflate sub during the generation process above? (or whatever I want to call it)

Comment: It seems like your code is generating setter methods every time an object is created.  All those methods will go into the `My::Object` namespace potentially overwriting methods created by the last call to `new`. Generating setter methods seems like something that ought to happen when the class is initialised - not when a instance of the class is created.

Comment: That is a very good point. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question ... I must write my own deflate methods.